# Check if none of given strings contains a certain string

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a list of variables declared for a string value. It is from an external source, there could be 5-10 variables. How do I check if all of them do not contain a certain string ("K.K")? I do not want to check for each such as

```
public string string_1;
public string string_2;
public string string_3;
...
...
...

if(string_1!= "K.K") //for all the strings for non-array collection
{}
...
...
...
```

Comment: I want to check if all my strings do not contain a certain string. I know I can add all of them to array but I am receiving all the variables as non-array, So how do I make the code compact while checking?

Comment: Add them to a list and then loop over it?

Comment: With "contain", do you mean "must not contain the substring" or "must not be equal to" (as per your code sample)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know how do get your variables into an array/List

```
var strings = new List<string>();
strings.Add(string_1);
strings.Add(string_2);
strings.Add(string_3);
...
```

or

```
var strings = new List<string>{string_1, string_2, string_3, ...};
```

or

```
var strings = new []{string_1, string_2, string_3, ...};
```

you could e.g. use [Linq `Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any) and as filter [`string.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.contains) or also [`string.Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.equals) depending on your needs

```
if(!strings.Any(s => s.Contains("K.K")))
{
    ...
}
```

---

Alternatively to using `Equals` if you know your strings should all be **unique** you could also use

```
var strings = new HashSet<string>();
strings.Add(string_1);
strings.Add(string_2);
strings.Add(string_3);
...
```

or

```
var strings = new HashSet<string>{string_1, string_2, string_3, ...};
```

and then simply check

```
if(!strings.Contains("K.K"))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks alot :D

Comment: @Magnetron yep, thanks ^^ Typing on the phone :D